# java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set Java

Tags: java, sql

I'm getting `java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set` when I try to use this code:

```
ResultSet user = query("SELECT `id`, `counter` FROM `accounts` WHERE `username`='test'");
int id = user.getInt("id");
int counter = user.getInt("counter");
System.out.println("Id: " + id + " | Counter: " + counter);
```

All I really need to do is get the values of id and counter and set it to an integer in java but I'm not sure how to do that this is the third method I've tried, is there anything else I can do to get that information? I know for a fact the problem isn't with my query method so I figured it'll be pointless to show it, this is pretty much the entire snippet. (Yes the connection is opened and closed no problem) Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace (with some more information) of the exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a call to `user.next();` **before** trying to read the first row. You are literally **before** the first row. Typically, you would use a loop like

```
while (user.next()) {
    int id = user.getInt("id");
    int counter = user.getInt("counter");
    System.out.println("Id: " + id + " | Counter: " + counter);
}
```

The [`ResultSet.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) Javadoc says (in part),

> A `ResultSet` cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method `next` makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

Comment: Fixed it, haha! Would you mind explaining why that fixed it?

Comment: @JohnLeo I added a link to the javadoc and a quote, but it's as I said in my second sentence - you are *literally* before the first row.

Comment: This also helps 'user.first();'. It works regardless of where your cursor at the moment is.